# how to use com.android.mms.transaction package in my app

Tags: android

I am working on MMS app, I need to use "com.android.mms.transaction" this package in my app..

please suggest me which JAR file I need to include my app to access this package..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what object(s) you need in your app, but if you can't find any compiled jar files that contain this library, you can make your own using the open source app created by Google.
The com.android.mms.transaction package can be found [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#dpDz7Q08o9c/src/com/android/mms/MmsApp.java&q=com.android.mms&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc).